Incoherence in the Duggan-Schwartz theorem- How is this possible?.
In voting theory the Duggan-Schwartz theorem is the generalization of the Gibbard-Satterthwaite theorem.
Informally it states: Any deterministic ranked voting system with 3 or more alternatives, with residual resoluteness, non-dictatorship, and citizens' sovereignty, must be manipulable.
For a formal description I'll let the link to this page: Gibbard-Satterthwaite generalized.
As I understand it, the theorem only states that some situations must be manipulable under those characteristics, not all of them; it addresses every voting system, but not every possible case within any voting system.
However, this raises another question: if the theorem does not apply to every case, and instead allows for situations that avoid manipulability, why does it specifically require $3$ or more alternatives? The theorem would work exactly the same if it were written with $2$ or more options, or if there were no alternative limitation at all, would not?
So, why is that? Why did they decide to specify "$3$ or more" when it seems to work for any number of alternatives?
Maybe it's an obvious thing, but it isn't for me — any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you want a written explanation of a topic, Wikipedia is a great resource. Posting on this site works better when you have a specific problem that you're stuck on.

I actually have a specific problem, and i write it down here but it was closed.

In social choice theory, a voting rule is a function for a specific amount of voters and alternatives. The rule does not need to generalize to different amounts of alternatives, in contrast to what we would informally call a voting system. That is, we might see "plurality voting" as a single system, but for this purpose "plurality voting with 3 alternatives" and "plurality voting with 2 alternatives" are separate voting rules.
Indeed, plurality voting with 2 alternatives satisfies all the conditions put forward in the theorem, and is thus a counterexample to the extension of the theorem to voting rules with 2 alternatives.
